# Tensorflow probability: retrieving specific random variable from joint distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, mixture-model, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm new to tensorflow probability.
I am building a hierarchical model, for which I use the *JointDistributionSequential* API:

```
jds = tfp.distributions.JointDistributionSequential(
[
    # mu_g ~ uniform on sphere
    tfp.distributions.VonMisesFisher(
        mean_direction= [1] + [0]*(D-1),
        concentration=0,
        validate_args=True,
        name="mu_g"
    ),
    # epsilon ~ Exponential
    tfp.distributions.Exponential(
        rate=1,
        validate_args=True,
        name="epsilon"
    ),
    # mu_s ~ von Mises Fisher centered on mu_g
    lambda epsilon, mu_g: tfp.distributions.VonMisesFisher(
        mean_direction=mu_g,
        concentration=np.array(
            [epsilon]*S
        ),
        validate_args=True,
        name="mu_s"
    ),
    # sigma ~ Exponential
    tfp.distributions.Exponential(
        rate=1,
        validate_args=True,
        name="sigma"
    ),
    # mu_t_s ~ von Mises Fisher centered on mu_s
    lambda sigma, mu_s: tfp.distributions.VonMisesFisher(
        mean_direction=mu_s,
        concentration=np.array(
            [
                [sigma]*S
            ]*T
        ),
        validate_args=True,
        name="mu_t_s"
    ),
    # kappa ~ Exponential
    tfp.distributions.Exponential(
        rate=1,
        validate_args=True,
        name="kappa"
    ),
    # x_t_s ~ mixture of L groups of vMF
    lambda kappa, mu_t_s: tfp.distributions.VonMisesFisher(
        mean_direction=mu_t_s,
        concentration=np.array(
            [
                [
                    [
                        kappa
                    ]*S
                ]*T
            ]*N
        ),
        validate_args=True,
    name="x_t_s
    )            
]
)
```

I then intend to create a mixture of those models using the *Mixture* API:

```
l = tfp.distributions.Categorical(
probs=np.array(
    [
        [
            [
                [1.0/L]*L
            ]*S
        ]*T 
    ]*N               
),
name="l"
)

mixture = tfd.Mixture(
cat=l,
components=[
    jds
] * L,
validate_args=True
)
```

This doesn't work. What I intend to mix upon is the random variables at the "end" of the hierarchical model, the *x_t_s*, of batch shape (N, T, S). I guess I need to feed those to the *components* argument for the mixture. The problem is that I can't easily retrieve those variables from the *model* object.

Does anybody see a way around this problem ?

Note that I tried using the *jds.model[-1]* instead of *jds*, but this points to the lambda function, which isn't what I need here.

Answer (score 0):

Several thoughts here.

1. Consider `SphericalUniform` for the first distribution.
2. For `Mixture`s of the same type, consider using `MixtureSameFamily`.
3. Put the mixture into the hierarchical model. i.e. instead of that last distribution being a vMF, it could be a `MixtureSameFamily(Categorical(...), VonMisesFisher(...))`.
4. If you later want to access components, you can call `ds, xs = jds.sample_distributions()`, and look at `ds[-1].component_distribution`

Feel free to email tfprobability@tensorflow.org w/ questions too.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help :)
1- Thanks for the tip, but won't this make my posterior look weird ?
2-3- I considered that design, the issue is that if I do this, the L means for the `x_t_s` vMF will be drawn from the same `mu_t_s` distribution, am I right ? what I want is to generate L independant `mu_g`, resulting in different `mu_s` and `mu_s_t` distributions

Comment: 4- the `sample_distributions` method returns a vMF indeed, but instanciated with given parameters, is there a way to return the RV as the result of the `jds` distribution, so that calling this RV's sample method would generate new parameters each time ?

Comment: 1 - the distribution is identical, it won't change anything, it's just more concise

Comment: 2/3 - this is a bit too detailed to resolve in a comment. You might want to think about using tfd.Sample, to avoid all the array stacking you're doing to replicate the parameters of these distributions. it can be helpful to look at the batch_shape and event_shape attributes of distributions.

Comment: 4 - all distributions in TFP are normalized, so the only way to "generate new parameters every time" is to call `sample` on the joint. if all you want is the last part, you can write `jds.sample()[-1]`. If you want 100 samples with different parameters, you can write `jds.sample(100)`.